# Strange Linking error in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

Im compiling below code snippet

```
cv::Mat frame ;
tld->processImage(frame);
```

and Getting following linker error

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall tld::TLD::processImage(class cv::Mat)" (?processImage@TLD@tld@@QAEXVMat@cv@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Now I have changed the code to something like this

```
Mat frame ;
tld->processImage(0);
```

and Getting below linker error

error C2664: 'tld::TLD::processImage' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'cv::Mat'
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

The problem is when I call the method tld->processImage(frame) Im getting this linker error "unresolved symbol" but when I call this method with incorrect type as parameter it gives another "cannot convert parameter" error thus acknowledging the fact that method is there.

This problem occurs only with the processImage() method.
Im able to call other methods of "tld" without any problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your original problem means that you're missing (atleast one obj-file when linking). The new error is obvious and is a compiler error: you don't have a conversion from int to Mat...

Comment: Could you post some more info about your TLD class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're most likely missing a reference for `cv::Mat`. If the TLD class is working elsewhere it is almost certainly because you don't have an include for `cv` in the place you're making this method call.

If you have multiple includes for `cv` you should add to the top of the header file;

```
#ifndef CV
#define CV
```

And at the bottom of the file add;

```
#endif
```

This will ensure that file is only compiled once, and used to solve a lot of linker problems for me when I wrote c++ often.

Answer (score 0):

`C++` has two phase to convert your code into executive code, first is compile and second is link. In first phase compiler look for code syntax and in this phase it understand that you have a function named `processImage` that take one argument of type `cv::Mat`, but in second phase linker look for its implementation and can't find it, did you implement that method or just declare it?? if answer is yes, did you include source(`.cpp`) file that contain your implementation in link process?? If function is from an external library, did you include that library in list of libraries that passed to linker?? By answering this questions I'm sure you can always solve `unresolved external symbol` error of the linker :)

Comment: Thanks a ton for clearing the air !!!. This would certainly help me in debugging such errors. Thanks for saving lot of my time :)